# Why do most vehicles seen at airports use slow flashing orange beacons?

Tags: airport-vehicles

Most vehicles seen at airports use slow flashing orange beacons rather than a rotating beacon, is there a purpose to this? What is the correct name?

Answer (score 21):

**ICAO**

Mobile obstacles at airports are lighted with *type C obstacle lights*, this refers to airport lighting practices defined in [ICAO in Annex 14](https://www.bazl.admin.ch/bazl/en/home/specialists/regulations-and-guidelines/legislation-and-directives/anhaenge-zur-konvention-der-internationalen-zivilluftfahrtorgani.html):

> 6.2.2.6 Low-intensity obstacle lights, Type C, displayed on vehicles associated with emergency or security shall be flashing-blue and those displayed on **other vehicles** shall be **flashing-yellow**.

*Rotating vs. flashing*

There is no difference in rotating vs. flashing. Flashing is used with modern technologies, e.g. LED, as the number of on/off cycles has little impact on lifetime, contrary to filaments which are subject to thermal fatigue when temperature changes.

*Flashing frequency*

From same ICAO document:

> Table 6-1. Characteristics of obstacle lights
> Low-intensity, Type C (mobile obstacle): Flashing (**60-90 fpm**)

This choice is likely based on physiological considerations, to limit ocular fatigue, and impact of a repeating signal on brain.

*Color*

Red/blue are for emergency/safety vehicles, orange for support vehicles.

[image]

<sup>[Source](https://www.icao.int/NACC/Documents/Meetings/2012/2012AerodromeCertification/ACIW14.pdf)</sup>

**FAA**

FAA implements ICAO recommendations in [AC 150/5210-5](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentNumber/150_5210-5).

> *Airfield Service, Aircraft Support, and Airport Operations Vehicles*
> The standard for identification lighting is a yellow flashing light that is mounted on the uppermost part of the vehicle structure. A steady yellow light designates vehicles limited to non-movement areas. [...]
>
> 4. TLTVs. An LED light bar placed above the operator’s cab may be used in place of the rotating yellow flashing light. In  addition, a yellow  flashing  light  (of  any  type) must be installed on the upper left-rear and right-rear corners of the TLTV, and must be activated  when an aircraft  is in tow.

For color:

> 1. *Airport Emergency Vehicles.*
>    a. Ambulances. Per  the  most  current  version  of  Federal  Specification  KKK-A-1822.
>    b. ARFF Vehicles.  Red or a combination of red-and-white flashing lights per the chromaticity requirements in Appendix B.
> 2. *Airport Security Vehicles*.  Signal blue or a combination of red and signal blue flashing light per the chromaticity requirements in Appendix B.
> 3. *Airfield Service, Aircraft Support, Airport Operations, and Other Vehicles.* Yellow flashing light per the chromaticity requirements in Appendix B.

For frequency:

> Lights must flash at 75 ± 15 flashes per minute